# Errno 1: Operation not permitted while running cron job in crontab

Tags: python, macos, cron

I know this is a common error and it's been asked many times here on SO. I've been through all the solutions and none of them are working for me.

I'm using crontab on my iMac (running Catalina) to set up a cron job:

`42 11,20 * * * cd path/to/directory && echo <password> | sudo -S /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3 filename.py >> log.txt`

The full error I'm getting:

`Password:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3: can't open file 'filename.py': [Errno 1] Operation not permitted`

I've tried:

- Allowing Terminal to have Full Disk Access
- Setting permissions on the files in the directory with sudo chown my-username:my-groupname filename
- Adding password in the command

but this error never changes.

Any help gratefully accepted.

Comment: Can you check the system logs if any related warnings or errors were logged when that command was being run? (my grammar is probably wrong)

Comment: What is the "path/to/directory" where the script is? If it's in a user directory that Apple's Transparency Consent and Control (TCC) system considers private, you're probably running into a TCC limit. Granting Full Disk Access to Terminal doesn't help with cron jobs, since they don't run under Terminal. You might be able to grant access to cron itself (see the comments [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/341958/full-disk-access-for-backup-tool-running-as-cron-job)), but it'd be better to move everything to non-private locations.

Comment: @VPfB I'm not sure exactly what to look for there but I didn't see anything with 'cron' in the name around the time it last ran.

Comment: @GordonDavisson the folder was actually in my Dropbox folder at the time. I dragged it out to Desktop and rewrote the cron job to reflect the new location, but I'm getting exactly the same error.

Comment: @MBWD The Desktop folder is also considered a private location. Try putting it somewhere not inside a user's home directory.

Comment: @MBWD I'm not a Mac user, cannot help with logging details. On a Linux system I would suspect a non-standard sudo config (very uncommon) or SELinux preventing the file access.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I seem to have resolved the permissions error, but now I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'`. I'm importing a bunch of modules for this file and again that was something working without issue when I was just running it manually... nothing about the code has changed, so any idea why this error now?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this. These are steps you can try to follow:

1. Open up System Preferences -> Security & Privacy (Mac OSX Catalina)
2. Open Privacy tab
3. Click Full Disk Access
4. Ensure your version of python has been added to the list of application with access.

To do this, just find out where in your system Python is located, navigate there by pasting the path into Finder->Go->Go To Folder, finding the exe file, and dragging it into the Full Disk Access section of Privacy.